# Eclipse won't debug on ASUS eee TF101

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I've got an app that I'm trying to debug on my ASUS eee TF101 **(not rooted)** and it's not working.  Whenever I click "debug" in Esclipse, my ASUS shows the "The application .... has stopped unexpectedly.  Please try again." error message.  I'm able to run this on my EVO (rooted) and a DroidX (non-rooted) without any issues.  I've made sure all the applicable settings have been applied ([Setting up a Device for Development](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)) as well but it still doesn't work.  The strange part is if I put a breakpoint on the 2nd line of code in the onCreate event, it doesn't even break there:

```
boolean bNetworkConnected = true;
```

I figured a simple assignment statement would work for a breakpoint but it doesn't break there.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

**UPDATE**

Maxim, I cannot run it in release mode either.  I've made sure the MainActivity is the one specified in the manifest file (remember, this runs on my evo and droidx).  Here's a copy of LogCat when I ran it in Release mode:

---

```
02-14 10:31:21.107: D/dalvikvm(5934): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 4% free 6370K/6595K, paused 40ms
02-14 10:31:21.117: I/dalvikvm-heap(5934): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.767MB for 513744-byte allocation
02-14 10:31:21.157: D/dalvikvm(5934): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 6872K/7111K, paused 25ms
02-14 10:31:21.197: E/GetStringFromWebService ERROR-(5934): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-14 10:31:21.207: E/GetStringFromWebService ERROR-(5934): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-14 10:31:21.207: E/GetIntFromWebService ERROR-(5934): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null"
02-14 10:31:21.207: E/GetStringFromWebService ERROR-(5934): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-14 10:31:21.207: D/AndroidRuntime(5934): Shutting down VM
02-14 10:31:21.207: W/dalvikvm(5934): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40221760)
02-14 10:31:21.227: D/dalvikvm(5934): GC_CONCURRENT freed 67K, 3% free 6908K/7111K, paused 2ms+4ms
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adacel.app/com.adacel.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at com.adacel.app.MainActivity.GetLatestData(MainActivity.java:300)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at com.adacel.app.MainActivity.LoadWithNetworkConnectivity(MainActivity.java:220)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at com.adacel.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:79)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
02-14 10:31:21.227: E/AndroidRuntime(5934):     ... 11 more
```

It appears as if it's erroring out on the method GetStringFromWebService.  But the strange part is this....that call isn't made until further down in the MainActivity...my assignment call above (bNetworkConnected = true) is the 2nd line of code, just after super.onCreate(savedInstance)...so it's like it doesn't even see the breakpoint that I set there.

**MainActivity Code**

```
public static final String TAG = "SQLiteDebug";
private ListView mListViewIssues;

private static final String NameSpace = "RemoteWebService";
private static final String URL = "http://ws.simcare.biz/Service1.asmx";
private static final String DBVersionKey = "DBVersion";
private static final String PreferencesNotLoaded = "User Preferences could not be loaded. \n\nThis app will now close.";
private static final String CustomerCodeNotLoaded = "The Customer Code could not be loaded. \n\nThis app will now close.";
private static final String LocationShortNameNotLoaded = "The Location Short Name could not be loaded. \n\nThis app will now close.";
private static final String DBVersionNotLoaded = "The Database Version could not be loaded. \n\nThis app will now close.";
private static final String App_File = "app_file.xml";
private static final String AppNotConnectedTitle = "App Not Connected to Network";

Boolean ConnectedToNetwork = false;
TextView tvFooter;
int DBVersion = 1;
IssueInfoCreator creator;
AppPreferences appPrefs = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);        

    setContentView(R.layout.footer_layout);

    //For testing network connectivity only.
    boolean bNetworkConnected = true;

    //If there's a network connection available, get latest data.
    //if(NetworkUtils.getInstance(this).isOnline(this)){
    if(bNetworkConnected){                      
        //Load data from web service and get latest data.
        LoadWithNetworkConnectivity();
    }
    else{   
        InputStream isAppFile = null;
          try {
              isAppFile = getBaseContext().getAssets().open(App_File);
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            ShowMessageAndClose(PreferencesNotLoaded);
            return;
        }

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(isAppFile);
        String sScannerContents = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        Document doc = XMLfunctions.XMLfromString(sScannerContents);

        try{
            if(LoadPreferences(doc))
                DBVersion = Integer.valueOf(appPrefs.getDBVersion());               
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("INT PARSE ERROR", ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }

        //Load data from local db only.
        LoadWithoutNetworkConnectivity();
    }

    //Load listview control.
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //Setup Refresh button listener.
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);
    btn.setOnClickListener(btnRefreshClick); 

    final Context context = getBaseContext();
    mListViewIssues = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listIssues);

    //Load Footer View.
    View footerView =((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.footer_layout, null, false);  
    tvFooter = (TextView)footerView.findViewById(R.id.footerText); 
    tvFooter.setText("DBVersion = " + String.valueOf(DBVersion)); 
    mListViewIssues.addFooterView(footerView);  

    creator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, DBVersion);
    creator.open();

    //add data to listview through adapter.
    mListViewIssues.setAdapter(new IssueInfoAdapter(this, creator.queryAll()));

    creator.close();
 }
```

**LoadWithNetworkConnectivity code:**

```
private void LoadWithNetworkConnectivity(){
    //Set the Titlebar to the stored value in the DB.
    String SoapAction = "RemoteWebService/GetApplicationTitle";
    String MethodName = "GetApplicationTitle";
    setTitle(GetStringFromWebService(NameSpace, MethodName, SoapAction, URL, "ApplicationName", "AndroidApp"));

    //Get the DBVersion.
    SoapAction = "RemoteWebService/GetDBVersion";
    MethodName = "GetDBVersion";
    DBVersion = GetIntFromWebService(NameSpace, MethodName, SoapAction, URL, "ApplicationName", "AndroidApp");

    //Write DBVersion to Preferences.
    Editor ePreferences = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    ePreferences.putInt(DBVersionKey, DBVersion);
    ePreferences.commit();

    //Get Issues for this Customer/Location.
    SoapAction = "RemoteWebService/GetOpenIssues";
    MethodName = "GetOpenIssues";
    SoapPrimitive xmlData = GetDataFromWebService(NameSpace, MethodName, SoapAction, URL, "ApplicationName", "AndroidApp");

    try {
        GetLatestData(xmlData);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Set flag.
    ConnectedToNetwork = true;
}
```

**GetDataFromWebService code:**

```
public SoapPrimitive GetDataFromWebService(String NameSpace, String MethodName, String SoapAction, String URL, String argName, String argValue){
    try { 
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NameSpace, MethodName);         
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        envelope.dotNet = true;

        request.addProperty(argName, argValue);

        if(MethodName == "GetOpenIssues")
        {
          request.addProperty("CustomerCode", "ABC");
          request.addProperty("LocationShortName", "KBIF");
        }

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        androidHttpTransport.call(SoapAction, envelope); 

        SoapPrimitive responseData = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        return responseData;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        Log.e("GetStringFromWebService ERROR-", new RuntimeException(e).toString());
        return null;
    } 
}
```

**GetLatestData code:**

```
public void GetLatestData(SoapPrimitive xml)throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException{
    //get the factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    //Using factory get an instance of document builder
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc;

    //parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml.toString()));
    doc = db.parse(is);

   //Clear out Issues table first.
   creator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, DBVersion);
   creator.open();
   creator.ClearIssueTable();
   creator.close();

   NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Table");

   for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
       IssueInfo issue = new IssueInfo();

       Element e = (Element)nodes.item(i);

       issue.setIssueNumber(Long.parseLong(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "IssueID")));
       issue.setIssueSummary(XMLfunctions.getValue(e, "IssueSummary"));
       issue.setDateReceived(DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());

       if(issue.getIssueNumber() > 0 && issue.getIssueSummary() != null){
           creator = new IssueInfoCreator(this, DBVersion);
           creator.open();
           creator.InsertIssue(issue.getIssueNumber(), issue.getDateReceived(), issue.getIssueSummary());
           creator.close();
       }
   }
}
```

There's the code you requested....in short, the app starts, checks to see if there's a valid network connection (in this case, I just put a bool flag so I don't have to keep unplugging my cable or disconnecting my wifi to make it work/not work), and it runs the appropriate method.  I set the flag to true so it calls the LoadWithNetworkConnectivity() method....this method goes out to our .NET web service and gets the application title, DBVersion, and OpenIssues.  In this method it then calls the "GetLatestData" method and parses the XML into an Issue object that I created.  Again, all this is working find on the emulator, evo, and droidx, just not my ASUS tablet.

**UPDATE #2 - RESOLUTION**

I skipped the effort with trying to get my tablet to debug and created an emulator for 3.2 OS (I was running it on 2.3.3 emulator before).  So now I can debug and see where the error is coming from.  It appears to error out FIRST on the following line:

```
setTitle(GetStringFromWebService(NameSpace, MethodName, SoapAction, URL, "ApplicationName", "AndroidApp"));
```

If I put this in a string, it returns null and the error I get in LogCat is:

```
02-14 16:01:21.177: E/GetStringFromWebService ERROR-(510): java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

Just like Maxim said, you have to put the networking stuff on it's own thread.  The Android SDK documentation explains it as well [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html).  Unreal what it says there...it's allowed on older platforms but not on Honeycomb and above, which is what the ASUS tablet is running, which is why the error is coming about.

Thanks Maxim for helping me out!  Once I get the code to put the networking events on it's own thread, I will try to update this post so others will know.

Comment: Tiny chance something wrong with the device, I can debug everything on my TF101. Does it crash when you run your app not in a debug mode? Is it your main launch activity? If not, did you declare that another activity in the Manifest file? LogCat would help here.

Comment: Can you post your `MainActivity` code? specially `com.adacel.app.MainActivity.GetLatestData` method

Comment: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adacel.app/com.adacel.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException, this means you are getting somewhere null as an object and trying to get something from that null. Also ERROR-(5934): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null". First of all make sure WebService call done in a separate thread, because of (NetworkOnMainThreadException). Second, you are getting correct data from Service. Look inside LoadWithNetworkConnectivity()

Comment: @Maxim - I understand the int being null error and that's what I'm trying to debug, which I can't.  The minute I put a breakpoint on anywhere in the onCreate event, it doesn't get picked up.  What's really strange is why is it working on all the other devices that I tested it on?

Comment: I'm glad my suggestions helped you to solve the problem. I put that comment as an answer, if you mark it as an appropriate answer, that will be my appreciation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your LogCat errors say where problem can be hidden.

1. Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.adacel.app/com.adacel.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException, this means you are getting somewhere null as an object and trying to get something from that null.
2. Also ERROR-(5934): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "null".
3. NetworkOnMainThreadException (Network call is done in a main thread)

First of all make sure WebService call done in a separate thread, because of (NetworkOnMainThreadException). Second, you are getting correct data from Service. Look inside LoadWithNetworkConnectivity()

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you have already installed on the device the APK of the same application. Even worse, if you did it through Market. You should simply uninstall APK. BTW, you have forgotten to put Manifest here.

Comment: Definately not published to the market, this is local to my company and we'll install it on the Tablets as needed.

Comment: And APK? Have you installed it by USB copying and later installation by some manager?

Comment: I've never installed it with any app, I've only been connecting the device to my pc via USB and running the app in Debug mode in Eclipse.

Comment: Sorry then. Also check, if you have allowed the usb debugging mode in the device itself. LG Optimus has this option in preferences.